# Wiring a 3 Pole Meross Light Switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I've got a three-pole light switch that I would like to get wired up in my house, and after opening the panels it appears that the wiring is nontraditional:

- The Fixture: Ceiling Fan with light attached
- Porch Gang

  - Switch 1 can turn our fixture on and off, but only if the toggle 1 is set to on (So something is obviously wired incorrectly here).
  - Switch 2 is unimportant to us, but I would guess it's single pole and controls the porch light
- Fridge Gang

  - Toggle 1 correctly turns on and off the fixture
  - Toggle 2 controls the overhead light in the kitchen, again I think it's single pole.
- Replacement switch is a [Meross Smart Wi-Fi 3-Way Switch MSS550 US](https://www.meross.com/en-gc/smart-switch/homekit-switch/24) 
  Let me know if you need any additional information, thanks!

Images:

[image: Fridge Gang]

[image: Fridge Gang, brightened]

[image: Replacement Switch]

[image: Porch Gang]

[image: Porch Gang, brightened]

[image: Porch Gang 2]

[image: Porch Gang 2, brightened]

[image: Porch Gang 3, brightened]

## Updated photos:

[Album](https://imgur.com/a/7nhzhrP)

Comment: In the first picture "fridge gang" toggle #1 is that a black wire on the green screw?  If so that can be a problem.  Should only have bare or green wire on the ground screw.

Comment: Wow yeah. The "fridge gang" toggle #1, they obviously changed the switch for aesthetic reasons (wanted Decora) and didn't know the difference between a 1-way and 3-way switch.  So they attached one of the travelers to the safety ground terminal.  Since it's a plastic box, this doesn't trip the breaker, and the yoke and cover plate screws are energized half the time.  You need to suspect every switch and outlet in the building!  Either you need to skill up a lot to handle this, or get a pro. But a pro could be here all day. I'd recommend the "skill up" thing if you're game.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a black wire on the ground screw. I presume that the red is considered live or "common" while the black and white are travelers? Another frustrating thing is that across the board people seem to say "White is neutral" which is needed for smart devices, but then I start learning about three-way switches and suddenly white can be a traveler as well.

I am willing to learn about this stuff for my future homes, do you have recommendations for resources? Especially related to this specific issues?

I've got four of these three-pole switches.

Comment: Neutral must be white(sometimes grey), but white can also be a hot(240v, switch loops), should be marked black or red, plus  traveller.  Green or bare always ground.  Black, red and most other colours are used for hot/power.  Always take pictures before undoing wires.  With three and four way that is the most important.

Comment: @crip659, I have some additional photos here that. I tried adjusting and at one point the entire breaker switched back automatically which was quite scary, but with everything out of the wall I'm hopeful that it will be helpful. [Imgur Album](https://imgur.com/a/7nhzhrP)

Comment: Breakers DO NOT switch back on by themselves.  You either had the wrong breaker off and were playing with live power, or your breaker panel might be one of the few that is known to be bad.  Take a picture of your panel with labels showing and ask a different question.  Just to be sure you do not have major problems.

Comment: @crip659 No I mean I was testing a configuration I had set up and when I clicked the breaker back on it immediately switched into the off position. Smelled a bit of ozone when I jogged back upstairs to check things out.

Comment: That they are suppose to do when we goof up.

Comment: Yes I figured it was better than then coming upstairs to an electrical fire. Does it seem like I should be able to find a solution just based on the sheer number of wires I have in the second batch of photos? The main questions I have are:

- Of the four conduits going in to the porch gang, which are for the interior light?

- Do I have a neutral wire in either of the gangs?

Comment: Am I correct that in porch gang switch 1, the black and white go into the same cable, and the black wire goes to a black screw?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, yeah that's the kind of messed up wire they were going with...

Comment: So yes to my questions?

Comment: Affirmative. Sorry the colors got a bit washed out. Would it help if I reuploaded?

Comment: @MrSaiclops Nah, I can hit the edit history and see the old pix (I was the one who lightened them so we could see cables in the box).  I need what the photo does not show.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica They're live photos which helps me see the detail a bit more. Next time I disconnect I'll be super clear about the photos, but [please look in this album](https://share.icloud.com/photos/056stvq3d_uX-8siywpkSf5Dw) to see if you can make heads or tails. I so appreciate the help!

Comment: If you have more photos, [edit] them into the question or stick them on Imgur. Apple Photos makes you jump through too many hoops to access the pix. I tried to download and got a ZIP file containing no JPEG at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a big job that needs big prep

You're wasting time by chasing all the wrong things. What you actually need is cubic knowledge.  What you're doing is random unproductive stuff - googling madly... **experimenting with random hookups** which is always a no-no since there are many combinations that will work *and then KILL YOU*... writing long threads of Q&A... and whatever on earth you did "posing" all the wires spread out, which benefits us not at all, and destroys essential clues.

What you need to do is look at a few **books** on home electrical and pick the one that feels most accessible to you, and read it cover to cover.  Really.  Google doesn't work: it only answers questions, it doesn't tell you *which questions to ask*. **You need a well-rounded primer on the subject.** You need basic domain knowledge so you know what to do with grounds, are comfortable with white not being neutral sometimes, can recognize the travelers on a 3-way, etc. etc.

I'm sorry, I know there's a Be Nice Policy, but you're driving me *crazy* with how you're plinking knowledge, as if *one single info-nugget* will be your silver bullet to a problematic house wired by others who clearly were also "plinking", a lot. That person left you a significant technical debt.

### The issues at hand, though

I'm really reluctant to go through this thing point by point, because if you follow the above advice, you'll catch all that.  Let me hit on what won't be in the books.

First, that insulated green wire is weird. The concern is it might not be proper in-wall wiring, but the wire looks "solid" not stranded, and that's a good sign it's intended for in-wall wiring.   I wouldn't worry about it, treat it same as bare (except strip the insulation, obviously, anywhere you want it to make contact!)

The grounds are wrong but you'll figure that out as you skill up.

At the fridge switch, they wired a 1-way switch where a 3-way switch need to be, heinously attaching black to the safety ground of the switch.   But at the porch switches, they used a 3-way switch for the right side switch that is not a 3-way. So these are the kinds of mistakes they are making - see where "skill up" matters?

Probably because the person who went to the home store got the wrong kind "Normal vs Decora" (the wide opening) and so the person used the wrong switch so they would have Decora. The lesson there is to own a variety of cover plates so you aren't sweating that. Cover plates are like 20 cents.

Note the most important rule of smart switches on 3-ways: You don't get to decide where the smart switch goes. That is dictated to you (forced down your throat) by the topology of the existing wiring.  If you have your heart set on full 3-way UX/functionality at a place where the "smart switch" cannot go, then you need to get a brand of smart switch master/servant pair, which allows full functionality at the servant unit.  That may not be your first choice of brand, but you have to live with that.

The "fridge gang" contain two *switch loops* and smart switches can't go there, as no neutral exists in the box. Not only that, they appear to be on two different circuits, and even if neutral could come there, you can't cross circuits with a neutral.

A "cable" is multiple "wires" which run inside a sheath.

On the left 3-way, see where the white and black go into the same cable sheath, but the other wire on the switch goes into a different cable?  3-ways have 2 travelers, and they always run in the same cable.  So as wired, black and white are travelers.  However, on 3-way switches, travelers always go on the brass screws, and black is on a black screw.

[image]

As you can see, 3-ways are not that complicated *logically* once you are clear on the 2 travelers.

I also advise getting clear on what a MWBC is (Multi-Wire Branch Circuit aka Shared Neutral) and for that it helps to understand US split-phase, so you can be on the lookout for those.

### Get it working as it is, before trying to innovate.

The problems I see in the wiring look fixable, but you need to get to a baseline of "working" before you can attempt to modify it.  I get the desire to try to "do it in one", but that requires everything to go perfectly and that's not happening.

So I would correct the 3-way switch mess first. Once that is working tip-top, you can think about smart switches.

Comment: Much appreciated. My understanding of electrical work clearly has a long way to come but I am quite willing to read whatever is necessary to get me there. I've picked up [this book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54353621-ultimate-guide) from the local library and will be going cover to cover each night after work.

Thanks for the more detailed aid on my specific situation.