# Completely Re-Wiring a Three-Way Light Switch (Meross MSS550)

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, multiway-switch, smart-switch

**The Scenario:** I've just discovered that the previous owners of my home did not care for electrical safety and wired the boxes in very dangerous ways 
**What I'm looking for:** Assistance re-wiring the two boxes. Best case scenario I can turn the overhead light into a smart one, but at the very least I would like this to not be such an electrical hazard.
**The basics:** You can find the [original post I made here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/276744/wiring-a-3-pole-meross-light-switch). I'm sorry if it's annoying that I opened a new thread, but I genuinely think this is a new issue altogether since I'm no longer just adding a switch, but completely redoing the wiring. 
**Diagram:**
[image: Pretty, huh?]

**Suspicions:** Based upon my minimal knowledge, I would guess that the green cables connect. They are green in the illustration because they're green in real life. Do I have proof of this? No.

I also *think* I might have a situation [like this](https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/3-way-swtich-light-between2.gif), although I obviously have two 12-3 cables coming in to the Porch Gang box, where the illustration has only one.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have conduit and not cable?  Conduit will make life a bit easier, you can find where the wire goes by just giving it a little pull.  And it is good to open a question for a different answer if it changes the original  question completely.

Comment: @crip659, Oh it is probably cable. I wasn't sure of the phrasing, but I've given it a tug in hopes that I could assess which is which and I got nothing.